# Oracle VM virtualbox does not show option for Windows OS 64-bit versions

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am on Linux Mint 19.03.

I want to set a 64 bit Windows 10 into a virtual machine, however it does not prefer me to choose a 64 bit of any windows version, as shown in the figure.

Anybody here to help me to understand why it is so?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PC can only virtualize 32 bit OS'es because you have not enabled the virtualization features in your BIOS.

Giving exact instructions here is difficult, as every BIOS is a little different.

The settings should be called 'Intel Virtualization Technology', 'AMD-V' or similar and appear mostly in the CPU settings.

Regarding the Hyper-V comment: Hyper-V is a Windows virtualization technique and does not exist on linux machines.